# Position of figures

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

I have a question: can I put 3 pictures one beside the other in the same line? 
Actually I put them one after the other and I would like to put them in the same line if is possible. This is my code

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,clip,trim=0cm 0cm 8cm 0cm]
   {t1}
  \bf{\caption{Nb des pages qui ont reçu la pub partagé dans le réseau Num 5}}
\end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,clip,trim=0cm 0cm 8cm 0cm]
   {t2}
  \bf{\caption{Nb des pages qui ont reçu la pub partagé dans le réseau Num 7}}
\end{figure}
\newpage
 \begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,clip,trim=0cm 0cm 8cm 0cm]
   {t3}
  \bf{\caption{Nb des pages qui ont reçu la pub partagé dans le réseau Num 9}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could format your code samples by highlighting the code and pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: You're trying to fit three images, each with a width of `0.4\linewidth`, on a single line (which has a width of `1\linewidth`). Do you want them to extend into the margins?

Comment: No I would not extend them into the margins but If it is possible I will change that

Comment: `\bf{\caption{..}}` is not the correct way to make the caption bold. `\bf` doesn't accept and argument and is outdated for once, but `{\bfseries\caption{..}}` isn't really correct either. Have a look at the `caption` package which should allow you to change the font for the captions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to insert subfigures you can follow Tobi's advice and do like the following (adapted from: http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/novices/sidebyside.html):

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[width=0.33\linewidth]{0.33\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{circle}
    \caption{A Circle}
    \label{fig:circle}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{rectangle}
    \caption{A Rectangle}
    \label{fig:rectangle}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{tringle}
    \caption{A Triangle}
    \label{fig:triangle}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This may require some adaptation to centre the contents of the `figure` environment. Like adding `\centering` outside the `minipage`s. Otherwise you'll have a `.01\linewidth` gap on the RHS. Additionally, what will happen if the image is greater than `0.33\linewidth`?

Comment: Thank you very much for all this answers but when I try some solutions that you suggested I think it is better to leave the 3 figures one after the other because when I put them one beside the other it isn't very clear.

Comment: @Werner, you're right. I changed with width of each of the image examples to 0.33\linewidth. I thought the 0.1 was negligible, but one can change to 0.3333… or center them all outside the minipage. And of course only use 3 images like that if you want them to be much smaller.

Comment: @Joseph: Actually, the image widths should be `\linewidth`, not `0.33\linewidth`, since `\linewidth` adapts to the width of the line inside the current environment. In this case its set by `minipage` to be `0.33\linewidth` (equivalent to `0.33\textwidth` at that point), implying that `0.33\linewidth` image is actually `0.1089\linewidth` wide... Try it, using `\rule{0.33\linewidth}{50pt}` for your images/`\includegraphics` instead. Unless, of course, that's what you meant in the first place.

Comment: @boutheina: You should upvote all questions you find helpful (by clicking the upward-pointing triangle next to each answer), and accept the one that you found most helpful. This is true for all of your questions, by the way (you haven't upvoted or accepted any answers yet).

Comment: @Werner, you're right, I hadn't realized that \linewidth was the width of the *minipage*...

Comment: @Jake: thank you for your advice I accepeted the answer that I think it was the most helpful but it doesn't resolve my problem

Comment: @boutheina: Then you need to clarify your question. As it stands, the question is: "How do I put three pictures on the same line", and all the answers do exactly that. You can edit your question to add more information.

Comment: @boutheina: I was also concerned with the fact that you hadn't upvoted any answers. The system shows you've now issued one upvote, but looking at the various answers you've received, surely there are more helpful answers than that.

Comment: @Jake: that is true but I think that the answer that I upvote is the most helpful and the others are not because when I tried this it doesn't give me what I want.

Answer (score 9):

TeX doesn’t mind how many figures you ut inside a `{figure}` environment so you can just put three images in one. Add `{minipages}` to align them.

[image: fig-align]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{img1}
      \caption{My first image.}
   \end{minipage}
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{img2}
      \caption{My second image.}
   \end{minipage}
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3.7cm]{img3}
      \caption{My third image.}
   \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Notes**

- Insid of a `{minipage}` the `\texwidth` equals the width of the `{minipage}`
  an not the main text
- With the optional argument of `{minipage}` you can align them vertically.
  Possible values are `c`, `t` or `b`
- The `\hfill` fills the rest of the line (i.e. `0.1\textwidth`) with white space.
- Certainly it’s not requiered to set the `height` of the images explicitly. I did
  it just to demonstrate the `{minipage}` alignment.

Another way is to use sub figures as Edo shows in his answer.

Comment: No one cares, especially TeX...! :)

Comment: @Werner: Thats what I meant :-) [Is this ambiguous in my answer? I’m no native speaker so pleas correct it :-)]

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this in several ways. One way is to use the `subfig` package. Then you can add as many images as you want and LaTeX will try to arrange them on the same line. Here's a small example, edited as suggested.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!t]
        \centering
        \subfloat[3-nearest neighbors]{
            \includegraphics{someimg}
        }
        \subfloat[5-nearest neighbors]{
            \includegraphics{someimg}
        }
        \subfloat[7-nearest neighbors]{
            \includegraphics{someimg}
        }
        \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Which gives as result:

[image]

Comment: To build an example with inamges without needing to have real images you can use the `graphicx` package with the option `demo` and `\includegraphics[width=xx,height=yy]{someimg}`will print a black rectangle. That’s preferred against building the images with Tikz which blows up the code unnecessarily. Otherwise you can just use `\rule{width}{height}` to print a black rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Tobi, sorry for not respecting the etiquette.

Comment: In my eyes there’s no problem with you etiquette ;-) I just wanted to show an alternative way that’s better for minimal examples, in my opinion. In your example you may use real values for `xx` and `yy` or leave them out, so `graphics` uses the default (`demo`) values …

Comment: Just a comment on the placement option, you've used `[!ht]` which is better (but equivalent) to the `[!h]` in the question but unless there is strong reason not to, including `p` as well is always a good idea. Disallowing `p` (and `b`) floats just increases the chance that no acceptable position for the floats will be available so they will all go to end of document.